# How to set the width and height of a Raphael JS paper same as those of its containing div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

My Raphael JS paper is created inside a div with id 'temp'. I want the height and width of the paper to be same as those of the div temp. How do I go about doing this using javascript or jquery?

**HTML**

```
<div id="temp" style="border:1px solid red;width:500px;height:500px"></div>
```

I tried getting the height and width using

```
document.getElementById("temp").style.width 
document.getElementById("temp").style.height
```

but when I use it to create the paper, I am getting a JS warning..

Comment: have you tried anything.... show us your code..

Comment: This is the HTML - <div id="temp" style="border:1px solid red;width:500px;height:500px"></div> I tried getting the height and width using document.getElementById("temp").style.width and document.getElementById("temp").style.height but when I use it to create the paper, I am getting a JS warning..

Comment: what warnning do u get ??

Comment: This is the warning **Unexpected value _firebugIgnore parsing height attribute.**

Comment: Since the title asks about how to set the paper width and height in Raphael, I'll add a link to Raphael's [`Paper.setSize( width, height )`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setSize)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use.. [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) jquery function to get the height and width of the element..

```
var width=$("#temp").width(); 
var hieght=$("#temp").height(); 
alert(width); //gives you width
alert(height); //gives you height
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the following RaphaelJS init in your javascript:

```
var paper = new Raphael('myDiv');
```

In html:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
```

Here the raphael paper will be 200px by 200px. It does it automatically.